# SQL multiple OR chain query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a single table where I am attempting to access rows via a simple SQL query I think, however, I am misunderstanding the way the OR modifier technically works. The statement I am trying to query is as follows:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE name OR vehicle OR state OR address LIKE '%input term here%';
```

This either returns an empty table, or in some instances the entire table. If I pare down the statement to include 0 OR modifiers it works, the trouble begins when I attempt to chain them like above. I'm looking for the simplest way to have one single query for the table, I think this might not be possible the way I'm going about it though. Any ideas?

NOTE: I am sanitizing input, I changed the end of the query for readability.

Comment: You need to add `LIKE '%input term here%'` for every column you want to apply it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to repeat the `LIKE` expression for each column, i.e.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE name    LIKE '%input term here%' OR
      vehicle LIKE '%input term here%' OR
      state   LIKE '%input term here%' OR
      address LIKE '%input term here%'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * from table 
WHERE name LIKE '%input term here%' 
OR vehicle LIKE '%input term here%' 
OR state LIKE '%input term here%' 
OR address LIKE '%input term here%';
```

try this out